# JTextfield Focus between two JInternalFrame

Tags: java, focus, jtextfield, jinternalframe

In my application I have 3 classes that extends `JInternalframe`. One is `MainFrame`. Suppose `Mainframe` has four `JTextFields`. `TF1, TF2, TF3, TF4`. When the `MainFrame` is opened `TF1` got focus by default.

Now user will press enter and go to `TF2`. In the next step depending on a condition Another JInternalFrame `SubFrame_1` or `SubFrame_2` will get opened as a floating window.

`SubFrame_1` has four different TextFields. `TF5, TF6, TF7, TF8`. Again `TF5` got focus by default. Some calculations will be done here and when user presses enter in `TF8` `SubFrame_1` will be disposed. And the MainFrame should regain focus in `TF3`.  The same condition may be applied to `SubFrame_2`. But when SubFrame_1 is disposed `TF3` never gain focus. More horrible thing is that sometimes the MainFrame does not get focused when the SubFrame is disposed. How can I get rid of this issue? I've tried all sort of function `requestFocusInWindow()`, `requestFocus()`, `grabFocus()` etc. Please help.

Comment: Please post some samaple code.

Comment: Is it technically possible or not ?

Comment: Seems possible but cant be sure until I see the code and understand properly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can I have an working example ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my small example:

`public class Form1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {`

```
/**
 * Creates new form Form1
 */
public Form1() {
    initComponents();
    this.jInternalFrame2.setVisible(false);
    this.jInternalFrame3.setVisible(false);

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jInternalFrame1 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jInternalFrame2 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
    jInternalFrame3 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
    jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jInternalFrame1.setTitle("JIF1");
    jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);

    jButton1.setText("Focus In JIF 2");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

    jTextField2.setText("jTextField1");

    jTextField3.setText("jTextField1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame1.getContentPane());
    jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame1Layout);
    jInternalFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jInternalFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 179, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jInternalFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jInternalFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jInternalFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 109, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    jInternalFrame2.setVisible(true);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame2.getContentPane());
    jInternalFrame2.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame2Layout);
    jInternalFrame2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jInternalFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jInternalFrame2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jInternalFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 128, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    jInternalFrame3.setTitle("JIF2");
    jInternalFrame3.setVisible(true);

    jTextField4.setText("jTextField4");

    jTextField5.setText("jTextField5");

    jButton2.setText("Focus in JIF 1");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame3.getContentPane());
    jInternalFrame3.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame3Layout);
    jInternalFrame3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 284, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jInternalFrame3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jInternalFrame1)
                .addComponent(jInternalFrame2))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jInternalFrame3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(121, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jInternalFrame3)
                .addComponent(jInternalFrame1))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jInternalFrame2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    this.jInternalFrame3.setVisible(true);
    this.jTextField4.requestFocus();
    this.jInternalFrame1.setVisible(false);
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    this.jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);
    this.jTextField3.requestFocus();
    this.jInternalFrame3.setVisible(false);
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Form1().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame2;
private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: In a single class it is absolutely possible. In single file I have many options other than JInternalFrame. But I have three classes that extends JInternalFrame.

Comment: Thats why I said "your req. are not clear". Simple alternative might be passing the instance of the JInternalFrame and create public method which will set the focus on the required field